# Maven deploy "Release Note" as artifact

Tags: java, maven, deployment, devops

**Requirement**: Upload (deploy) an additional file (a text format release note file) along with jar/war to nexus.

**Possible Solution**: Use `maven deploy plugin` as below:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy-file</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <packaging>RELEASENOTE.MD</packaging>
                        <generatePom>false</generatePom>
                        <url>${project.distributionManagement.repository.url}</url>
                        <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                        <file>RELEASENOTE.MD</file>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

**Problems**:

1. `RELEASENOTE.MD` file is optional. The file should be deployed only if it is present. The above solution throws an error if the file is not present.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.4:deploy-file (default)
>   on project ...\RELEASENOTE.MD not found.

2. Need an option to specify file name by regex (example: `*RELEASENOTE.MD`). `maven deploy plugin` does not accept regex.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.4:deploy-file (default)
>   on project ...*RELEASENOTE.MD not found.

How can these two problems be circumvented?

Comment: Why not simply checking in that artifact in your version control ? or adding in during the build via build-helper-maven-plugin ?

Comment: Yes it will be checked in to version control. But it is optional. Not all jars will have a release note. So the plugin should not try to deploy the file if it is not present.

Comment: Than the appropriate projects which creates the jar should attach the release notes to the project and not the deploy-plugin. BTW: Why should teh release notes put into the repository and not on a generated site ?

Comment: Whether the release note is a static file in repo or generated (by jenkins, for ex) is the second step. The question if the file exists (and only if the file exists), how do we deploy it to nexus.

Comment: As mentioned before use the build-helper-maven-plugin to add this as supplemental resource to the original build of the jar file that's it...maven-deploy-plugin is not the right way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining the inputs from **@SpaceTrucker** and **@khmarbaise**, came up with the following solution:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>add-release-note</id>
        <activation>
            <file><exists>RELEASENOTE.MD</exists></file>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>attach-artifacts</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <artifacts>
                                    <artifact>
                                        <file>RELEASENOTE.MD</file>
                                        <type>MD</type>
                                        <classifier>RELEASENOTE</classifier>
                                    </artifact>
                                </artifacts>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

**Edit**

- `maven-deploy-plugin` within profile activation works too. However, it poses a difficulty for release/snapshot build parameterization due to its `<url>` tag. `build-helper-maven-plugin` is a simpler solution
- Filename regex can be handled through a wrapper shell build script

Answer (score 1):

Move the deployment of the release notes to its own maven profile and activate that profile only if the release notes file is present.

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <file>
        <exists>RELEASENOTE.MD</exists>
      </file>
    </activation>
    <!-- deployment of release notes declarations here -->
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

See [Introduction to Build Profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) for more information.

Regarding the regex requirement you should set up a naming policy for the release notes and implement that as variable accessible by the maven build. The [build helper maven plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html) might be of use there.